# Cassandra DB change many rows where = null

Tags: cassandra

I have table with many millions rows. I added new field, and this is `null` in old rows, so I  need to update it to 0, can I do it?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. You can update the value of new column. For this you can write a utility which will scan the complete table and update record one by one. If you are aware with spark and use it then things will be easier and faster.

Comment: could you clarify this with some links?)

Comment: also how can I make search where = null?

Comment: You need to fetch the  complete record in memory and then read the values of column  (whether it is null or not ) in memory. You should not search in Cassandra directly as it will be very slow and it is not recommended in Cassandra to search without partition key. With respect to spark, will ask you to explore https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector and spark documentation.